# Ruby iterator upto method numbering arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby, iterator

```
1.upto(3) do |n|
  arr"#{n}" = Array.new
end
```

My goal is to end up with 3 empty arrays named like so.

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = [] 
arr3 = []
```

How do I make this code work?

Comment: Why are you not using a two-dimensional array or a hash with the value of `n` as key?

Comment: @guitarman
im too much of a noob to understand what you just said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to dynamically create local variables. That's a bad idea, and also <s>not easy</s> impossible to pull off.

As someone already suggested, use data structures for storing. You are effectively creating array, so why not use array for storing it:

```
arr = []
1.upto(3) do |n|
  arr << Array.new
end
```

or, if you need to keep custom indices, a Hash:

```
arr = {}
1.upto(3) do |n|
  arr[n] = Array.new
end
```

Comment: “also not easy to pull off” should be read as “impossible.” Also there is a `Binding#local_variable_set`, it is doing not exactly what might be suggested and there is no way to propagate local variables from one context to another.

Comment: For the record, local variables could be created u in Ruby v1.8 (using g `eval`), but not in later versions.